# Vuetify scrollable sheet inside container issues

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am trying to have a scrollable sheet that will become scrollable once the sheet becomes full of items. Right now the entire container scrolls instead of just the sheet.

The yellow area should take up all available space, which is why im using flex-grow-1, but i think this may be causing the lack of overflow in that sheet.

[Example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container style="height: 100%">
      <v-sheet class="d-flex" height="100%" width="100%" color="green">
        <v-sheet class="d-flex flex-column" width="300" color="grey">
          <v-sheet class="d-flex justify-center ma-2" color="transparent">
            <v-btn @click="addItem">Add Item</v-btn>
          </v-sheet>
          <v-sheet class="flex-grow-1" color="yellow">
            <v-sheet class="mb-5" color="transparent">
              <v-list
                lines="two"
                bg-color="transparent"
                mandatory
                nav
                width="inherit"
              >
                <v-list-item
                  v-for="item in items"
                  :value="item"
                  density="compact"
                >
                  <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <v-icon
                      icon="mdi-alarm-check"
                      style="margin-inline-end: 16px"
                    />
                  </template>
                  <v-list-item-title
                    class="user-select-none"
                    :title="item.name"
                  >
                    {{ item.name }}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                  <v-list-item-subtitle
                    class="user-select-none"
                    :title="item.description"
                  >
                    {{ item.description }}
                  </v-list-item-subtitle>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-sheet>
          </v-sheet>
        </v-sheet>
        <v-sheet class="ma-2" color="transparent">
          <div>
            <p>This area shouldn't be scrollable, only the yellow area.</p>
            <p class="pt-5">
              Add items until the yellow area overflows and then the whole
              container becomes scrollable
            </p>
          </div>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  const items = ref([])

  onMounted(() => {
    for (let i = items.value.length + 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      items.value.push({
        name: `Item ${i}`,
        description: 'Test description',
      })
    }
  })

  const addItem = () => {
    items.value.push({
      name: `Item ${items.value.length + 1}`,
      description: 'Test description',
    })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set CSS `height: 100vh` on your `v-app` element. This will make sure that the parent container will have a fixed height of 100% of the viewport.
Then we need to make the yellow part vertically scrollable by adding CSS `overflow-y: auto`.

So in summary update the `v-app` element to `<v-app style="height: 100vh">`. And update the yellow `v-sheet` to `<v-sheet class="flex-grow-1" color="yellow" style="overflow-y: auto">`.

Your [example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) but updated.